# Tin-can LRS query Statements can not grab my data

Tags: php, scorm, tin-can-api

I use Tin Can query to grab my scorm.
I want to grab which name = "Ming" but I would show all student....
I use API step by step,I don't know what's wrong?
this is my data:
[image: data picture]

this is my code:

```
    <?php
 
$loader = require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$lrs = new TinCan\RemoteLRS(
    'https://cloud.scorm.com/lrs/SFXXXXX/',
    '1.0.0',
    'accountXXX',
    'PWDXXXX'
);

$actor = new TinCan\Agent(
    ['name'=> '名 小'] 
);

 $response = $lrs->queryStatements(
            [ 'agent' => $actor, 
              'limit' =>8 ,
            ]
 
            );
?>
```

This is my reference:
[Tin-can reference](http://xapi.com/wp-content/assets/e-book/Anatomy-of-a-Tin-Can-Statement-e-Book.pdf)

please help me,thanks.

new:
I change my code to agent,
but it show:

```
he following 'agent' parameter contains invalid properties: 
'{"objectType":"Group","name":"\u540d \u5c0f"}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`actor` is not one of the available query parameters. You would need to use `agent`, and to filter statements by an Agent you have to provide the IFI, in your case the `account` value, `name` is not an acceptable identifier in xAPI so it can't be used as a filter value. The list of available properties matches the set of query string parameters listed in the `GET /statements` resource here: https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-Spec/blob/master/xAPI-Communication.md#213-get-statements

Comment: hello @Brian J. Miller ,I have change to agent, my problem's  code has revise. but it show "he following 'agent' parameter contains invalid properties: '{"objectType":"Group","name":"\u540d \u5c0f"}'"

Comment: @samurai You need to pass an Agent or Group that has an IFI (identifier). See https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-Spec/blob/master/xAPI-Data.md#inversefunctional for more about IFIs. What you are passing is an anonymous Group, because it does not have an identifier, which is not a valid parameter for filtering.